# How can I get an XML attribute by name instead of iterating over all the attributes?

Tags: xml, vbscript

I'm using vb script and MSXML2.DOMDocument  to parse a xml document.

Is it possible get a particular attribute by name instead of iterating over all the attributes?

Today I am doing this

```
For x = 0 To (curNode.Attributes.length - 1)
    sAttrName = curNode.Attributes.Item(x).nodeName
     if sAttrName = 'customer' then 
        avalue=curNode.Attributes.Item(x).nodeValue
```

but I want do something like this

```
 avalue=curNode.Attributes.Item("customer").nodeValue
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [getAttribute()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms761380%28VS.85%29.aspx), as in `curNode.getAttribute("customer")`.

I'm assuming that curNode is an `oXMLDOMElement`, though you didn't show its type.